# How to SUM value using PHP function for ORACLE

Tags: php, oracle, sum

Kindly help me.

I want to create a summary from raw database. Example:

```
ID | Vessel Name | Tonnage |

1      ABC         1000 

2      CDE         2000 

3      EFG         3000
```

---

6000 <-- How to total up this value using php and oracle?

for your information, below is my code:

```
 $conn = ......;
   $strSQL = .....;
   $objParse = oci_parse ($conn, $strSQL);
   oci_execute ($objParse);
   while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse,OCI_BOTH))
   {
    echo $objResult["ID"];
    echo $objResult["VSLNM"];
    echo $objResult["TON"];
   }
```

My question: is there any way using PHP function to SUM all tonnage value. I want to get grand total for all tonnage.

Comment: What's your SQL query at the moment?

Comment: Mr. Burhan Khalid already provide me with the expected answer. Anyway, thanks for your time sir!

Answer (score 0):

Its trivial, just add to a variable that you define outside your loop:

```
   $conn = ......;
   $strSQL = .....;
   $objParse = oci_parse ($conn, $strSQL);
   oci_execute ($objParse);
   $total_tonnage = 0;
   while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse,OCI_BOTH))
   {
    echo $objResult["ID"];
    echo $objResult["VSLNM"];
    echo $objResult["TON"];
    $total_tonnage += $objResult["TON"];
   }
   echo $total_tonnage;
```